# Prevent two arrow keys from outputting if pressed at same time

Tags: jquery, html, key

I have the following code (it basically changes the image I have set depending on the key I press).
The problem I am having is when the user presses **two keys at the same time.** (ex: Right Arrow key and Left Arrow key). How can I prevent output if **more than one key is pressed at the same time**?

```
  <div id="slide"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/r41vA8p.png" /></div>
  </div>

 $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
           $('#slide').html('<img src="img">');
        }
      if (e.keyCode == 38) {
           $('#slide').html('<img src="img">');
        }
      if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
           $('#slide').html('<img src="img">');
        }
      if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
           $('#slide').html('<img src="img">');
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Better Explanation:

> if left is pressed and held down, then simultaneously right is
>   pressed, no event should occur, nor toggle to right in that instance.

Comment: Can you throw it in a jsfiddle? From what I can tell, the last key down is what will show.

Comment: Sure no problem, http://jsfiddle.net/CcrjW/1/, It detects whichever key comes last, yup. I just want it to stay as it's default image if two keys are pressed at the same time.

Comment: The default being up? `on.('keyup')` set to up.

Comment: @WalkOfLife If interpret requirement correctly, if `left` is pressed and held down, then simultaneously `right` is pressed, no event should occur ? Not toggle to `right` in that instance ?

Comment: whatever is the last key down is what will be placed. combining keys is a bit trickier.

Comment: @guest271314 exactly.

Comment: ah. ill adjust my answer.

Comment: @WalkOfLife Not have moment to test thoroughly, presently, yet might begin with utilizing jquery's `.on("keydown.namespace")` then in `if` statement, try `if (e.keyCode == 37 && e.keyCode != 39)` . Tried briefly at jsfiddle, requires additional testting. Also, could attach an `.off(keydown.namespace)` `event` if certain keys pressed while within first event. All untested, just potential options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier if JavaScript supported the XOR comparison operator. I had to create the XOR with ANDs ORs and NOTs (&&, ||, !). But, it works.

Every time an arrow key is pressed it turns true in the map. If more than one is true at the same time do nothing, else change the image accordingly.

Every time an arrow key is lifted up it becomes false in the map.

```
var map = {37: false, 38: false, 39: false, 40:false};
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
         if((map[37] && !map[38] && !map[39] && !map[40]) ||
            (!map[37] && map[38] && !map[39] && !map[40]) ||
            (!map[37] && !map[38] && map[39] && !map[40]) ||
            (!map[37] && !map[38] && !map[39] && map[40])) {
            if (map[37]) {
                $('#im').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/BXeUGsv.png">');
            } else if (map[38]) {
                $('#im').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/MaU1zD0.png">');
            } else if (map[39]) {
                $('#im').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/kY8MnnC.png">');
            } else if (map[40]) {
                $('#im').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/r41vA8p.png">');
            }
        }
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
});
```

**Edit**

The old code allowed three buttons to be pressed. Fixed it.

Demo new code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EgJ97/)

---

Old answer fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Gs7A/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. And a clever way of doing it! Nice.

Comment: @WalkOfLife Check out the updated code. While the old code didn't allow 2 keys be simultaneously pressed it did allow for 3 to be pressed.

Comment: I didn't even notice. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly better way to make this happen.. recursive and uses `which` instead of `keyCode` (for cross-browser reasons).

**[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjBok/)**

```
var base,neutral,up,down,left,right;

  base = 'http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/hospital/image/600x600/';
  neutral = 'emergency.jpg';
  up = 'arrow-up.jpg';
  down = 'arrow-down.jpg';
  left = 'arrow-left.jpg';
  right = 'arrow-right.jpg';

var change_image = function(src){
  $('#slide img').attr('src',base+src);
}

change_image(neutral); //default

$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
  var k = e.which;
  switch(k){
    case 37:
      change_image(left);
    break;
    case 38:
      change_image(up); 
    break;
    case 39:
      change_image(right);  
    break;
    case 40: 
      change_image(down);   
    break;          
  }

}).on('keyup',function(){
  change_image(neutral); //default on keyup
});
```

*Ran out of time*

Essentially, you set "states" for each of the arrow keys on down, reset on up. The problem is `active_states` rises while an arrow key is pressed. Just fix that and you're good to go!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rBcGL/

Comment: +1 Edit, didn't notice your comment. Waiting for the adjustements :)!